# How does damage resistance work with same typed damage from multiple sources?

Tags: dnd-4e, damage-resistance

A scenario from our game last night.

We are facing monsters with an Aura 2 that causes 5 cold damage and stacks (enter or start turn in aura). These guys also have an attack that immobilizes and does ongoing 5 cold damage.

Our rogue has the Crown of the Winter King on (resist 5 cold).

During the round one of the monsters attacks her and she is immobilized and has ongoing 5 cold. She is also in the aura of 2 of the monsters.

How much cold damage does she take at the start of her turn?

- 10 because she takes 15 and only has resist 5

  *or*
- 5 because she resists both the save ends damage and half of the aura damage?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The character takes 0 damage.**

Being subjected to 3 instances of 5 cold damage does not stack, and each is resisted.

**Note** - I'm assuming you are referring to the Chillborn Zombie <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/monster.aspx?id=114)</sup> as it appears to match your description.

The Chillborn Zombie was created when the rule was that a creature was only subjected to one instance of damage from overlapping auras.  That rule was changed in [May 2010](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/UpdateCompiled.pdf).  When created, the zombie needed an exception noted in it's aura.  It isn't needed since the rule change, and there is no need to grant it a further exception.

> This change removes the rule that prevents stacking in damage auras, ensuring that 
>   monsters are achieving correct damage output

There is a discussion of this change on the [wizards boards](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19685882/Consolidated_Customer_Service_Answers?pg=75), with clarification from customer service.

Comment: That is the one I was referring to. Thanks for the rule change information, I will take a look when I have access to Wizards.