# Do overlapping damaging zones stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, zone

We know penalties from zones do not stack, but the rules appear to be silent about overlapping damaging effects.

If I'm in two zones that each do 15 fire damage, how much damage do I take?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Damage stacks. This has been clarified for overlapping auras and I don't see why it would not also apply for area effects.

In the case above you take 30 fire damage.

Comment: Can you cite the aura ruling? Is it Rules Compendium or WotC customer service? That's the inverse of ongoing damage, and so seems odd.

Comment: @SimonWithers the aura was a errata as of May 2010. http://www.enworld.org/forum/d-d-4th-edition-discussion/278370-quick-question-does-damage-auras-stack.html has the relevant quote.

Comment: @SimonWithers the aura question was also answered by Pat [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/8154/1084)